# Repairing broken plaster

Tags: ceiling, plaster

Removing some rotted wood above a window bay caused more destruction than would have been desired, and am hoping for some advice on how best to repair the holes in the plaster.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: this looks like it needs a lot of work (it looks like more than the wood was bad). I don't think there will be an easy way to fix this properly

Comment: You removed rotted wood on the inside??? If water go the the inside to rot the wood, it had to get past the wood INSIDE the wall first. That would be a major concern for me foremost. What Ack suggests is not difficult to do and replacing plaster with sheetrock is standard procedure. Now if there is rotted framing, that will be another matter and more pictures after you open up the ceiling.

Comment: upvote for ominous photos...

Comment: I'll be surprised if the exterior is properly weather-sealed. Looks like a lot of water damage as Jack pointed out. Be sure to look for water damage in the ceiling/wall and solve that before sealing it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like there is more damage likely hidden under the plaster and the wood members there would be structural. You should remove the plaster to get to and repair this damage or verify that there is none.

I suggest removing all the plaster of the relatively small area that is the ceiling of the bay window and replace with drywall after the repair work is done.